# Custom UITextLabel with picker wont display numbers when tapped on

Tags: ios, objective-c

Similar to how amazon does for selecting quantity of an item. I want it to then save the number to display in another tableview. Here is the code I have for my .m file. When I click on the text field the picker is empty.

```
@interface ApparelViewController ()


@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger numberOfComponents;

@end

@implementation ApparelViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

UIPickerView *picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
self.quantity.inputView = picker;

//creating the arrays for the values in the picker wheel

self.quantity0 = @[@1, @2, @3, @4, @5];

}


//custom picker in text field


-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
return  1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView     numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
return self.quantity0.count;
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:       (NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
return self.quantity0[row];
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row    inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
self.quantity.text = self.quantity0[row];
[self.quantity resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: There's multiple things you need to do to get this working, 1 tap gesture on a label, setup a popover with a incriminator and decrimentor. Tell another table view that there's a change in it. I suggest you try to implement as much as possible, when you hit a problem search stack overflow for help, if you don't find a relevant question open up a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to set the `UIPicker`'s delegate to `self`.

In your `viewDidLoad`, try this:

```
picker.delegate = self;
```

Comment: app crashes when I set it like that